# Vim: using collections in capturing groups (or: replace tags with different tags)

Tags: regex, vim

I have a Latex document where I wish to replace all mathmode tags `$ .. $` with their proper latex equivalent `\( .. \)`.

I have used this regex: `%s/\$\(.\+\)\$/\\(\1\\)/gc`, but this fails of course in the simple case that I have more than 1 tagpair in a line, i.e.

```
This is an example: $ 1+2=3 $ and $4+5=9$
```

What would be an easy way to fix that? I tried using a collection inside my capturing group like this: `\([^\$]\)` but this does not match.

Edit: The reason `\([^\$]\)` did not match is because I missed adding a quantifier to it like so: `\([^\$]\+\)`. This would've worked too, as the comments under the accepted answers show.

Comment: You may take care of some escaped $ (`\$`)? So it should allow \$ to be inside the math environment. But I don't know if and how some condition coud be realized. It may check if there is a \ in front when getting to a $

Comment: Amadan's answer worked fine for me. You're right though that one should think of escaped `$` signs, but luckily I don't have those in my case :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/\$\(.\{-1,}\)\$/\\(\1\\)/gc
```

Use non-greedy quantifier `.\{-1,}` instead of the greedy `.\+`.

`:help /\{`

Comment: Thanks!
This did indeed help. I was so focused on getting collections to work with capture groups, that I didn't even think about greedy vs. non-greedy!
Edit: Do you happen to know if collections work in capture groups? (just out of interest)

Comment: If by "collections" you mean character classes, they do: `:%s/\$\([^\$]\+\)\$/\\(\1\\)/gc` should do the same thing as the above.

Comment: @adaman Hmm, it didn't work for me, but I missed the `\+` bit. then again, I don't think it should be necessary.

Comment: It's not necessary if you only have things like  `$x$` and `$f$`. If you want to be able to handle expressions with more than one character inside, it is quite necessary. `[^...]` is "any one character not from this set".

Comment: This would then explain my failure in using this. Thanks for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a non-greedy qualifier as well, but change the condition to start/end a math environment:

```
:%s/\(\\\)\@<!\$\(.\{-1,}\)\(\\\)\@<!\$/\\(\2\\)/g
```

So I would use some lookbehind to make sure that a $ isn't after a \ which escapes it.

Comment: Your answer is too much magic for me.
Haven't tried it, Amadan's answer worked well for me, but it's good to have it here, in case someone else needs to take care of escaped `$` signs